# About the stackalert twitter bot

Tags: discussion, twitter

Is the stack alert twitter bot service still on? If not is there a similar service out there any where...?

Answer (score 2):

http://twitter.com/stackalert

No updates since Sep 1<sup>st</sup>. You can setup an account (using openid) with [Twitterfeed](http://twitterfeed.com), and make your own stackoverflow-twitter-bot to broadcast questions every 30 minutes or so from the RSS feeds.

Comment: Who put this together?  Was the bot banned by twitter or StackOverflow, or did they just stop running it?

Comment: It was apparently created by @ben_sim (http://twitter.com/ben_sim), and then influenced by @so_agg (http://twitter.com/so_agg - created by @teifion). A domain name was registered (http://www.stackalert.com) but nothing was really done with it.

Answer (score 1):

[Stack Trilogy](http://twitter.com/stacktrilogy) seems to be doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

Hello, I had the idea, then ceded it all to @teifion, who had started @so_agg before that (@stackalert was just a cooler name). I reserved the domain name and stuck up a page, just in case we hit the jackpot. It will expire in February 2010, if I remember correctly.

I subsequently gave up on Twitter completely, and didn't have any further contact with Teifion, though he has been on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15/teifion) fairly recently, and has an account [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/132042/teifion) too. So I have no idea if it was blocked, or he stopped, or something hung somewhere and he hasn't been to see why.